# Interface Matcher\RequestMatcherInterface' not found

Tags: php, symfony, web-deployment, symfony4, web-hosting

I am trying to deploy my Symfony app to Webhosting and getting this error

```
 Fatal error: Interface 'Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\RequestMatcherInterface' not found in /data/web/virtuals/201283/virtual/www/subdom/dev/vendor/symfony/routing/Matcher/UrlMatcher.php on line 29
```

My Webhosting haven't got SSH access, so I copied all folders except var and test. And then .env and composer.json to /subdom/dev (this subdom working with normal HTML index)

Using php 7.3.
Composer.json

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "^2.4",
        "knplabs/knp-time-bundle": "^1.9",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.3",
        "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/asset": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/console": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/form": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/intl": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "*",
        "symfony/process": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/translation": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/validator": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "4.3.*",
        "vich/uploader-bundle": "^1.10"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/profiler-pack": "*",
        "symfony/test-pack": "*",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "4.3.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "4.3.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I tried `echo interface_exists("Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcherInterface");` and it returns 1. But error is still here.

I don't know where to look next.

Comment: Could be an autoloading issue. How does your entry point of the app look like (`public/index.php` or `web/app.php`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for you, who read this. Don't argue with the error. If error say it's not found it's true and fix it. Something happend to Filezilla and some files weren't transferred correctly(was created with 0B size). So I copied them manually.

Comment: And your baseline is always true: when it says http error 403, you are not authorized or didn't give correct credentials. When it says file not found, its not there or not accessible. When it says disk full, it is full... #aDayInTheLifeOfASupportGuy

Answer (score 0):

According to your composer.json, `"symfony/routing": "4.3.*",` is missing, so the Symfony routing component is not available. However, I don't get why interface_exists returns true in your case...